# How to translate the contents of a scroll pane in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, translate, scrollpane, gridpane

Hello currently I am working on moving one's view of a scroll pane's contents depending on certain user interactions. In the application that I have a gridPane containing 3 image views of the same image that are each equal in size to the screen. All functions pertaining to zooming and panning work fine however if I try to translate the scrollpane (or its contents I have tried that) through the setTranslateX() and setting the parameters to the width of the screen I get either no change in the case of the contents or a blank screen in the case of the scrollpane. Below is my code if you substitute any image for the "WorldProvincialMap-v1.01.png" it should still work the same. The code doesn't generate any errors it just doesn't achieve the desired results.

```
package gameaspects;

import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SourceCodeVersion8 extends Application{

final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
public double SCALE_TOTAL = 1;
public static int game_speed = 5, day = 1, month = 1, year = -813, pause =               0;
public IntegerProperty dayProperty, monthProperty, yearProperty, pauseProperty, game_speedProperty;
public static double xDragStart;
public static double xDragEnd;
public static double xScaleToScreen, yScaleToScreen;
public static int dragTotal = 0;
public static int timesExpanded = 1;

static GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
static SourceCodeVersion8 sourceObject = new SourceCodeVersion8();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(task).start();
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Popup exitPopupO = addExitPopup();
    AnchorPane mapAnchorO = addMapAnchor();
    Scene mapScene = new Scene(mapAnchorO);
    primaryStage.setScene(mapScene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
    primaryStage.show();

    mapScene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if(e.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE)
        {
            exitPopupO.show(primaryStage);
        }
    });
}

//Creates an AnchorPane for the map
private AnchorPane addMapAnchor()
{
    AnchorPane mapAnchor = new AnchorPane();
    ScrollPane mapScrollO = addMapScroll();
    mapAnchor.getChildren().add(mapScrollO);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    return mapAnchor;
}

//Creates an ImageView for the map
private ImageView addMapView()
{
    Image mapImage = new Image("WorldProvincialMap-v1.01.png");
    ImageView mapView = new ImageView(mapImage);
    //Sets the map to full screen.
    int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    mapView.setFitHeight(height);
    mapView.setFitWidth(width);
    return mapView;
}

//Creates a gridPane to hold the ImageView
private GridPane addMapGrid()
{
    GridPane mapGrid = new GridPane();
    ImageView mapView1 = addMapView();
    ImageView mapView2 = addMapView();
    ImageView mapView3 = addMapView();
    mapGrid.add(mapView1,0,0);
    mapGrid.add(mapView2, 1, 0);
    mapGrid.add(mapView3, 2, 0);
    mapGrid.setManaged(false);
    return mapGrid;
}

//Creates a scrollPane for the map
private ScrollPane addMapScroll()
{           
    ScrollPane mapScroll = new ScrollPane();
    GridPane mapGridO = addMapGrid();
    mapScroll.setContent(new Group(mapGridO));
    mapScroll.setPannable(true);
    //Removes the ScrollBars
    mapScroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    mapScroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    //TROUBLED CODE HERE TRANSLATION ERRORS AND STUFF
    mapScroll.setTranslateX(gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth());
    //Adds functionality to scrolling
    mapScroll.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, e ->{
        //Consumes the event
        e.consume();
        if(e.getDeltaY() == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        double scaleFactor =
                  (e.getDeltaY() > 0)
                    ? SCALE_DELTA
                    : 1/SCALE_DELTA;
        //Ensures that you do not exceed the limits of the map
        if(scaleFactor * SCALE_TOTAL >= 1)
        {
            Bounds viewPort = mapScroll.getViewportBounds();
            Bounds contentSize = mapGridO.getBoundsInParent();

            double centerPosX = (contentSize.getWidth() - viewPort.getWidth()) * mapScroll.getHvalue() + viewPort.getWidth() / 2;
            double centerPosY = (contentSize.getHeight() - viewPort.getHeight()) * mapScroll.getVvalue() + viewPort.getHeight() / 2;

            mapGridO.setScaleX(mapGridO.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
            mapGridO.setScaleY(mapGridO.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);
            SCALE_TOTAL *= scaleFactor;

            double newCenterX = centerPosX * scaleFactor;
            double newCenterY = centerPosY * scaleFactor;

            mapScroll.setHvalue((newCenterX - viewPort.getWidth()/2) / (contentSize.getWidth() * scaleFactor - viewPort.getWidth()));
            mapScroll.setVvalue((newCenterY - viewPort.getHeight()/2) / (contentSize.getHeight() * scaleFactor  -viewPort.getHeight()));
        }
    });
    mapScroll.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, e -> {
        xDragStart = e.getX();
    });
    mapScroll.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> {
        xDragEnd = e.getX();
        if(dragTotal + (xDragEnd - xDragStart) >= gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth()/2)
        {

        }
        dragTotal += Math.abs(xDragEnd - xDragStart);
    });
    return mapScroll;
}

private Popup addExitPopup(){
    Popup exitPopup = new Popup();
    //Exit Panel
    VBox exitBox = new VBox();
    exitBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    Button exitPaneExit = new Button();
    exitPaneExit.setText("Return");
    exitPaneExit.setMinSize(75.0, 30.0);
    exitPaneExit.setOnAction(e -> {
        exitPopup.hide();
    });
    Button exitButton = new Button();
    exitButton.setText("Exit");
    exitButton.setMinSize(75.0, 30.0);
    exitButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        System.exit(0);
    });
    exitBox.getChildren().addAll(exitPaneExit,exitButton);
    exitBox.setVisible(true);

    exitPopup.setAutoHide(true);
    exitPopup.getContent().add(exitBox);
    return exitPopup;
}

static Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() throws IOException {
    long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Finds the current time and links it with a variable
    while(true)
    {
        if(pause==0)//Makes sure the game is not running while paused
        {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime >= 500 &&game_speed == 5)//Lowest game speed 10 seconds per day
            {
                day++;//Hey its tomorrow!
                sourceObject.setDayProperty(day);
                initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//Resets time
                if(day == 32)
                {
                    switch(month)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            sourceObject.setDayProperty(day);
                            sourceObject.setMonthProperty(month);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 8:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 10:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 12:
                            month = 1;
                            day = 1;
                            year++;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if(day == 31)
                {
                    switch(month)
                    {
                        case 4:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 9:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        case 11:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if(day == 29)
                {
                    switch(month)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            month++;
                            day = 1;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(month + " " + day + " " + year);
            }
        }
    }
        };
};

public final int getDayProperty()
{
    return dayProperty.get();
}

public final void setDayProperty(int day)
{
    this.dayProperty.set(day);
}

public final IntegerProperty dayInitialProperty()
{
    if(dayProperty == null)
    {
        dayProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
    }
    return dayProperty;
}

public final int getMonthProperty()
{
    return monthProperty.get();
}

public final void setMonthProperty(int month)
{
    this.monthProperty.set(month);
}

public final IntegerProperty monthInitialProperty()
{
    if(monthProperty == null)
    {
        monthProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
    }
    return monthProperty;
}
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `mapScroll.setTranslateX(...)` to do? I would assume it would just move the scroll pane horizontally the distance you specify: if that's the width of the screen it will be entirely off-screen, leaving you with a blank screen...

Comment: I expected it to move it in such a way that I can see the contents at the value entered in the parameters. So which function should I use to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Rephrased the question to not confuse people.

Comment: Do you actually need translation or are you just trying to set the scroll position of the `ScrollPane`?

Comment: I am trying to set the scroll position of the `ScollPane`.

Comment: Why not just use `mapScroll.setHvalue(...)` etc?

Comment: I had tried that earlier but misunderstood how it worked and entered in the wrong value. Figured it out and it works now. Anyone care to enter an answer to close this thread?

Comment: You could do that on your own, if you think this could be beneficial to others... In that case AFAIK you have to wait some time to accept it though. If you don't think others could benefit from this question there would still be the option of deleting it, which shouldn't get you into trouble as long as you don't do it too often...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to translate the contents I had to use mapScroll.setHvalue(); with a double as a parameter(not the pixels moved).